# Cropping image sometimes fails

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, crop, android-gallery

The users in my app have the option to take an image / choose from gallery and then crop the image. On most devices everything works fine but on some the cropping fails and an "Unable to save cropped photo" message appears (I know this happens on an HTC one m8 I dont have this device at hand to check on it). I am using xamarin for the development but it is basically the same code as in java.

Here is the code used to select from gallery:

```
protected void ChooseFromGallery ()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionPick, MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri);
            intent.SetType ("image/*");
            StartActivityForResult (intent, ChooseImageCode);

        }
```

This code handles the result:

```
if (requestCode == ChooseImageCode && resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            Uri selectedImage = data.Data;
            var input = this.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream (selectedImage);
            SharedContext.Bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream (input);
            CropImage (selectedImage);
        }
```

And here is the crop image method:

```
protected void CropImage (Uri imageUri)
        {            
            Intent intent = new Intent ("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            intent.SetType ("image/*");
            _targetUri = FileUtils.GetTempUri ();
            IList<ResolveInfo> list = PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities (intent, 0);

            int size = list.Count;

            if (size == 0)
            {
                Toast.MakeText (this, "Can not find image crop app", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                intent.SetData (imageUri);
                intent.PutExtra ("outputX", 640);
                intent.PutExtra ("outputY", 640);
                intent.PutExtra ("aspectX", 1);
                intent.PutExtra ("aspectY", 1);
                intent.PutExtra ("output", _targetUri);
                intent.PutExtra ("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png);
                intent.PutExtra ("scale", true);

                if (size >= 1)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent (intent);
                    ResolveInfo res = list [0];

                    i.SetComponent (new ComponentName (res.ActivityInfo.PackageName, res.ActivityInfo.Name));

                    StartActivityForResult (i, CropPictureRequestCode);
                } 
            }
        }
```

Did I miss something.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on an app where I crop screen shots like this:

```
**within fragment**

// get screen shot
Bitmap bmp = screenShot(v);
bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, v.getWidth(), 450);
```

method called to save:

```
// SAVE SCREEN SHOT TO INTERNAL STORAGE AND RETURN PATH TO IMAGE
// ****************************************************************
private String saveToInternalStorage(View v, Bitmap bitmapImage) {

    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(v.getContext());

    TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(v.getContext());
    int counter = tinydb.getInt("counter"); // get workout #
    String imageDir = weekWorkout[counter];

    // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
    File directory = cw.getDir(imageDir, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath = new File(directory, imageDir + ".jpg");

    ArrayList<String> imageAddressJpgList = new ArrayList<String>();
    imageAddressJpgList = tinydb.getList("imageAddressJpgList");
    imageAddressJpgList.add(counter, imageDir + ".jpg");
    tinydb.putList("imageAddressJpgList", imageAddressJpgList);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to
        // the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}

// TAKES SCREEN SHOT
// ********************
public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

TinyDB is a savedPreferences magic class I found on git btw.

I doubt this will help at all, but I just thought I'd like to start participating.